# The Majestic but Draconian Dinner

Tags: word-property

We are hosting a dinner party. Here is a list of things you can take:

```
Hotdog
Grapefruit
Oreos
Potato Salad
Cheetos
Utensils
Katlyn
Predator Drones
Banana
```

However, you may not bring in the following:

```
Cookies
Ginger Beer
Jellybeans
Ham Sandwich
Soda
Condiments
Zach
Peanut Butter
Dogs
Dishwasher
Basket
Tablecloth
Chocolate
Yourself
Umbrella
Tent shelter
Camera
Frisbees
Kite
Grapes
Spam
Lion
Cats
iPod
Speakers
Music
```

Quite a strange party indeed. How exactly are the organizers behaving?

Comment: I can’t take any of those things along if I can’t bring myself along too...